# Order by date diff in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I must find the most near event, in time, in a table.
If an event occurred 3 days ago, and the next one will be tomorrow, I want the second one. Viceversa if an event occurred yesterday, and the next one will be next month, I want the first one.

So I compose my query basing on the absolute difference in seconds between the dates, limiting to 1 result.

In pseudo SQL something like:

```
select * from events order by ABS(UNIXTIME(kickoff) - UNIXTIME(now)) limit 1
```

in LINQ:

```
Context.Events.OrderBy(m => Math.Abs( m.KickOff - DateTime.UtcNow ).TotalSeconds ).FirstAsync();
```

It work, but the order by is composed in memory and not in SQL "*The LINQ expression 'orderby Abs(([m].KickOff - DateTime.UtcNow).TotalSeconds) asc' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.*"

How I can have the order by query executed in sql?

**EDIT**

Removing Abs

```
Context.Events.OrderBy(m => m.KickOff - DateTime.UtcNow ).FirstAsync();
```

works as I want

```
[...] ORDER BY `m`.`kickoff` - UTC_TIMESTAMP()
```

but it don't give me the result I expect

Comment: Are you using .NET core?

Comment: Yes, c# in .NET core, I'll change the Tags

Comment: Just a guess, would this work: `.OrderBy(m => m.KickOff < DateTime.UtcNow ? DateTime.UtcNow - m.KickOff : m.KickOff - DateTime.Now)`? Basically: handle kickoff in past and future separately

Comment: @Hans Keﬆing , great job!! It work composing an order by with CASE. Thanks

Comment: @Longa glad that my guess did work out

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `Entity Framework` and `SQL Server`, you can use `SqlFunctions.DateDiff`, in `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`:

```
Context.Events.OrderBy(m => Math.Abs(SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", DateTime.UtcNow, m.KickOff)))
              .FirstAsync();
```

This assumes `now` as start date and `kick off` as end date. You can swap them if you need.

Comment: I'm using MySQL, but anyway, the query is not what I want: an absolute value for the seconds is needed.

Comment: @Longa you should be able to wrap it in a Math.Abs, most of the Math functions are supported by Linq to SQL by default. for example: Math.Abs(SqlFunctions.DateDiff("ss", DateTime.UtcNow, m.KickOff))

Comment: @ReeseDeWind I thought about that, but wasn't sure. Thanks for the tip. Updated the answer.